# Visual Basic - Change textarea content

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, browser

I want to change textarea from omeagle.com -> text cheat

The textarea has this code in HTML :

```
<textarea class="chatmsg " cols="80" rows="3"></textarea>
```

In visual basic I program my `webbrowser1` to navigate to this page. What do I need to do to change the text inside the textarea?

I've already tried this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("chatmsg").InnerText = "mycontent"
WebBrowser1.Document.All("chatmsg_area").InnerText = "this works"
WebBrowser1.Document.All("chatmsg_body").InnerText = "this works"
More ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not get an element by class name.  You can loop through all of the elements and check for a class name though.

```
Set NodeList = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementsByTagName("*")
For Each Elem in NodeList
    If Elem.GetAttribute("class") = "chatmsg " Then

        Elem.InnerText = "mycontent"

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Error : " Public member 'className' on type 'HtmlElement' not found."

Comment: Sorry about that.  The DOM available via WebBrowser1 is slightly different from the DOM that is available to other scripting languages like VBScript or Javascript.  I have modified the code which should work.

Comment: I am curious, was this helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `textarea` an id, then access it by its id.

```
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
....
WebBrowser1.Document.All("text1").innerText = "New text"
```